# Kullback-Leibler over discrete samples

Tags: r, probability, distance

I have two samples following two different distributions.
I'm trying to have a measure of the distance between those 2 distributions.
My idea was to get the kullback-leibler distance between those but I'm meeting difficulty since my samples don't cover the same space.

To illustrate my problem, I will use N(0, 1) and N(1, 1) as an example, but in reality, those distributions will not be normal.

In theory the KL distance between N(0, 1) and N(1, 1) is 0.5 as confirmed bellow:

```
# check with normal distribution pdf
p1 <- dnorm(-10:10, 1, 1)
q1 <- dnorm(-10:10, 0, 1)
z1 <- rbind(p1 / sum(p1), q1 / sum(q1))
philentropy::distance(z1, method =  "kullback-leibler" )
```

`kullback-leibler 0.5`

Now my two samples don't cover the same space, as illustrated bellow:

```
# discrete observations (ie only integer)
nbobsdiv2 <- 100
space1 <- data.table(x = sort(sample(x = -nbobsdiv2:nbobsdiv2, size  = nbobsdiv2*0.75)))
space2 <- data.table(x = sort(sample(x = -nbobsdiv2:nbobsdiv2, size  = nbobsdiv2*0.75)))

setkey(space1, x)
setkey(space2, x)

space1[, p := dnorm(x, 0, 1)]
space2[, p := dnorm(x, 1, 1)]
```

so I've tried either to get the union of both space, or the intersect to get the expected value of 0.5
First comparing the pdf observations over the *union* of both samples space:

```
# union of both space, filling missing pd with 0
space21.min <- max(min(space1), min(space2))
space21.max <- min(max(space1), max(space2))
space12.union <- data.table(x = sort(union(space1$x, space2$x)))[x >= space21.min & x <= space21.max, ]
setkey(space12.union, x)
pdf12.union <- space2[space1[space12.union]]
colnames(pdf12.union) <- c("x", "p2", "p1")
pdf12.union[is.na(pdf12.union), ] <- 0

kld12.union <- philentropy::distance(t(pdf12.union[, .(p1/sum(p1), p2/sum(p2))]), 
                                     method = "kullback-leibler")
kld12.union
```

`kullback-leibler  11.50815`

Then comparing the pdf observations over the *intersection* of both samples space:

```
# intersect of both spaces
space12.intersect <- data.table(x = sort(intersect(space1$x, space2$x)))
setkey(space12.intersect, x)
pdf12.intersect <- space2[space1[space12.intersect]]
colnames(pdf12.intersect) <- c("x", "p2", "p1")

kld12.intersect <- philentropy::distance(t(pdf12.intersect[, .(p1/sum(p1), p2/sum(p2))]), 
                                         method = "kullback-leibler")
kld12.intersect
```

`kullback-leibler  6.914469e-13`

So neither are working. I wonder which direction to take at this point?
My next idea would be to fit a distribution to my data and then generate samples but in reality my distributions d1 and d2 are probably non gaussian trimodal so this part would be problematic.
Any tip appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kullback–Leibler (KL) divergence is infinity when the probability distributions P and Q have disjoint support: [KL divergence between which distributions could be infinity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362860/kl-divergence-between-which-distributions-could-be-infinity).

Take this example:

```r
x <- seq(6)

P <- c(1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 0, 0)
Q <- c(0, 0, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4)
```

In theory, the KL divergence D<sub>KL</sub>(P ‖ Q) between the probability distributions P and Q is infinity. `philentropy::distance` calculates a finite D<sub>KL</sub> because it adds *epsilon* to every probability to avoid division by zero. See the documentation.

```r
philentropy::distance(
  rbind(P, Q),
  method = "kullback-leibler"
)
#> Metric: 'kullback-leibler' using unit: 'log'; comparing: 2 vectors.
#> kullback-leibler 
#>         5.063316
```

Consider other metric(s) for the distance between the two distributions. For example, the earth mover's distance (EMD).

```r
emdist::emd(cbind(P, x), cbind(Q, x))
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Funny enough, the Wasserstein distance was my next metric to test, which I understand is the same thing as the EMD...

Comment: Yes, EMD is another name for Wasserstein distance. But one of these two names is clearly more descriptive and fun.